# How can I ensure that my pronunciation of [ɛ] and [e] is correct in spoken English?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

As an intermediate English learner, when I talk to my American friends, sometimes they will misunderstand my [ɛ] and [e] sounds. For example, *measure* mistaken for *major*, *pepper* for *paper*, *and* for *end* ... etc.

What can I do to ensure that [ɛ] and [e] are easily differentiable?

Comment: As Ross notes, this question would be much easier to answer if we know your language background. With knowledge of your mother tongue, we could potentially give specific examples that relate between it and English.

Comment: The right way is fix this is to imitate the way your friends pronounce them. A quick fix I can think of at the moment is to make the length of duration clear. Most dictionaries would make it clear that it's /eɪ/ not just /e/ in *[paper](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/paper)*, while it's only /ɛ/ in *[pepper](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-cobuild-learners/pepper)*. So making the /eɪ/ sound longer than /ɛ/ should help. A more complicated fix is to get to know *tense & lax* vowels and *diphthongs*. They can help your pronunciation!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that the words *major, paper, hate, mate* have what is called a 'diphthong' in standard varieties of English. A vowel can be either a *monopthong* or a *diphthong*. A monopthong is a vowel sound in which the speech organs (hereafter *articulators*) remain more or less in the same position throughout the articulation of the vowel. That is, the vowel quality remains constant.

A 'diphthong', however, involves a change in the position of the tongue, thereby changing the vowel quality. The articulators glide from one vowel position to another.

*Paper, major, mate* have the diphthong /eɪ/ whereas *pepper, measure, met* have the monopthong /ɛ/ (sometimes transcribed /e/ for convenience). The [e] in some of the words you mentioned is a part of the diphthong /eɪ/.

Also note that /phonemes/ can be [[realised in more than one way](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/285703/106592)].

So when pronouncing *measure, bed, pepper* etc., make sure your tongue remains in the same position throughout the vowel sound. In some American accents, *major, mate, paper* have the long monopthong [e]. The main difference between [ɛ] and [e] is [vowel openness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_vowel); [ɛ] is more open than [e].

If you understand IPA, here are the transcriptions of 'day' (/eɪ/) in different American accents:

- Standard US: [dɛ̝ˑɪ]
- Ohio: [de̞ˑɪ]
- Chicago: [de̞ˑɪ]
- Boston: [deˑɪ]
- New York: [de̞ˑi]
- Alabama: [dɛ̝ˑɪ]

[All these transcriptions are from [Sound Comparisons](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/day)]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good audio example:

Paper:
http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=paper

vs.

Pepper:
http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=pepper&submit=Submit

A tip would probably be easier to provide if we knew what your mother tongue is.

Answer (score 1):

Like Damkerng T. says, the American English [e] is actually more-or-less a [ei] or [ɛi] diphthong.  So, for practice sake, try wedging in an explicit [i] (as in the word "bee") after the [e] and smooshing it into it.  That is, try pronouncing "paper" as [pɛi-pɛr] and major as [mɛi-jɛr].  You might start by making it three syllables [pɛ-i-pɛr], and then try running them together.

Comment: @snailplane Wait, is the American "a" in paper [ei] or [eɪ]? I thought it was [ei]. (I'm from Boston, if it matters.)  (Thanks for the rest of the IPA!)

Comment: Every online dictionary I've seen has it as [eɪ], even though it sounds more like [ei] to my Houstonian ears.

Comment: @Codeswitcher what's the difference between [ei] and [eɪ]? Is [eɪ] the same as [ej]?

Comment: @Anixx I think all three are supposed to be different, but I'd be hard pressed to differentiate [ei] and [ej].  As an aside, amusingly, I just discovered that on the wikipedia page for IPA, "IPA" is written in IPA, the the last is written as [eɪ], so I'm willing to concede the point!

Answer (score 0):

> My mother language is Chinese.

According to the [Chinese vowel diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_vowel_diagram) on Wikipedia, Mandarin Chinese includes the vowels:

- ㄝ (IPA [ɛ]), as in ㄧㄝˋ (夜, night).  This is the same as the first *e* [ɛ] in English *pepper*.
- ㄟ (IPA [ei̯]), as in ㄌㄟˋ (累, tired).  This is similar to the *a* [eɪ] in English *paper*.

(Disclaimer: I don't speak Chinese, and can't vouch for the accuracy of the above.)