# How to tell apart /ɝ/ and /ɛ/?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

Today I discovered the word "scurry" and I immediately found that I couldn't tell it apart with "scary". I looked it up and found that it boils down to differentiating /ɝ/ and /ɛ/, at least according to these Wiktionary entries:

- scurry

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scurry

Audio

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AEn-us-scurry.ogg

- scary

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scary

Audio:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3AEn-us-scary.ogg

They seem to sound the same to me at this point. How could I learn to tell the difference? One idea that comes to my head is to look for words that only differ by this sound, but I'm not sure how to start looking.

Comment: In my British accent the two words are completely different. In what kind of English do you find them indistinguishable?

Comment: They're also totally different in my American English accent (and all English accents I'm familiar with). May we ask what is your native language? It may help figure out why you're having trouble distinguishing these phonemes.

Comment: @TypeIA, kate I linked to the Wiktionary entries I used as the sources

Comment: Apart from its different sound, the pronunciation of the **u** vowel in 'scurry' is typically shorter than the **a** vowel in 'scary', which can be drawn out for emphasis. The Wiktionary pronunciation of 'scary' seems atypically short. To my BrE ears, it sounds like 'skerry' which is what they claim to be a homophone (but IMO isn't).

Comment: You have to hear it. The two are different phonemes.

Comment: I prefer this pronunciation of [scary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpIiSd-If6g), not because of its accent but because of the length of the vowel. There are other examples which sound like "skerry" but IMO that is said like that by someone for effect, like "it was so skerry" but who wasn't actually scared.

Comment: After listening to the linked clips, I think I can understand how some non-native speakers might have trouble distinguishing these sounds. (They sound very clearly different to native speakers of course.) It may help to consider some simpler minimal pairs: for example **fair/fur**, **pair/purr** and maybe even **hair/her**.

Comment: @TypeIA that's a good one: **scary** rhymes with **fairy** but not with **ferry**. A long vowel, not a short one.

Comment: Finding good and well-matched sound clips might not be easy.  Finding relevant words should be as easy as paging through nearly any English dictionary.  To hear them clearly, using text-to-speech AI (like [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=pl&text=The%20first%20lurid%20burdened%20bird%20scurries%2C%20and%20canaries%20carry%20scary%20flair.) might provide) is at least worth trying.  Learning to hear the difference and to pronounce it are related -- you want to do both at the same time.

Comment: @WeatherVane fairy and ferry are homonyms in many accents (or at least in mine, anyway)

Comment: When you say "scurry", and hold the *u* sound, you purse your lips (somewhat), sort of like the long oo in loon, and the jaw stays mostly closed. When you say "scary", and hold the *a* sound you pull your lips back and could open the jaw.

Comment: To me, the difference is as clear as that between chalk and cheese. What's your native language, might I ask?

Comment: @Apollyon: Polish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

/ɜ/, /ɛ/ and /ɝ/ are significantly different vowels. /ɜ/ and /ɝ/ are virtually the same vowel sound; both are central, the only notable difference is that the latter is being influenced by a following [ɹ]. /ɛ/ is a front vowel i.e. the highest point of the tongue is positioned relatively in front in the mouth.

#### Explanation

Vowels vary enormously from speaker to speaker. Also, different dictionaries use different systems to represent pronunciation; some use IPA, some use other systems.

Here's the vowel chart to begin with:

> > [image: Vowel chart]
>
> <sub>From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel)</sub>

How this chart (vowel quadrilateral) works is explained in detail by Patricia Ashby in [*Understanding Phonetics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Understanding_Phonetics.html?id=xb5EAQAAQBAJ):

> What the four-sided (‘quadrilateral’) figure shows us is a schematization of two dimensions of tongue movement, demarcating the boundaries of the vowel articulatory space within the oral cavity. The slanted left-hand line marks vertical displacement of the front of the tongue, showing us different degrees of open approximation. The top line, which we call **close** (as in ‘near to’), represents a position just wider than the degree of stricture required to generate friction. The jaw aperture is **narrow** and to reach this height, close, the front of the tongue is bunched up in the sort of position that also associates with the approximant consonant [j] (much like the sound at the beginning of English *yet*).

(p87)

In a nutshell, there are two main types of vowels based on the openness of the mouth:

- **Open vowel**: as the name indicates, the mouth is open and the tongue is positioned far from the roof of the mouth e.g. [a ɑ] (as in ᴛʀᴀᴘ and ᴘᴀʟᴍ, respectively)
- **Close/high vowel**: the tongue is positioned close to the roof of the mouth (but not creating any constriction because there's no constriction in vowels) e.g. [i u] (as in ꜰʟᴇᴇᴄᴇ and ɢᴏᴏsᴇ, respectively)
- Other vowels such as near-close, close-mid, mid, open-mid, near-open etc., lie in between open and close vowels.

The horizontal lines represent another feature of vowels called 'vowel backness'. It means whether the highest part of the tongue is positioned in the front or the back of the mouth. The same book (*Understanding Phonetics*) says that: "Vowels are made well back in the vocal tract, using only the body of the tongue – the front, centre and back. In terms of place of articulation, therefore, *they are located between palatal and velar*" (p84). On the basis of backness, vowels are primarily divided into three main categories:

- **Front vowel**: the highest part of the tongue is located relatively in *front* in the mouth e.g. [i e æ **ɛ**]
- **Back vowel**: the highest part of the tongue is position relatively *back* in the mouth as in [u ɑ ɔ **ʌ**]
- **Central vowel**: the tongue is positioned halfway between front vowels and back vowels as in [**ɜ** ə ɐ]

There's another feature called **vowel roundedness** which means whether or not the lips are rounded during vowel production. In the chart, some vowels occur in pairs such as [i, y], [ɨ, ʉ], [ɛ, œ] etc., the ones to the right side are rounded whereas those to the left side are unrounded.

Here are some transcriptions for *scary* from dictionaries that use IPA:

- Scary → /ˈsk**ɛː**ri/, /ˈsk**ɛə**ri/, /sk**ɛ**ri/

it can either be pronounced with a long vowel /ɛː/ or a short one /ɛ/ (the only difference is 'vowel length', not 'vowel quality'), or even with a [diphthong](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272891/106592) /ɛə/ (it involves a change of position of the tongue i.e. from /ɛ/ to /ə/). /ɛ/ is called open-mid, front, unrounded vowel: it's a front and unrounded vowel. In articulating [ɛ], the tongue is positioned one-third of the way from an open vowel [a] to a close vowel [i].

- Scurry → /ˈsk**ʌ**ri/, /ˈsk**ɝː**i/, /ˈsk**ɜ**r.i/

*Scurry*, on the other hand, can be pronounced with /ʌ/, /ɜ/ or /ɝ/, depending on the variety of English:

- the one with /ʌ/ is mostly used in British English
- the one with /ɜ/ can also be found in British English and in some American accents
- the one  with /ɝ/ is only found in rhotic accents such as General American

There's a significant acoustic difference between /ʌ/, /ɜ/ and /ɝ/:

- **/ʌ/ vs. /ɜ/:** The difference between /ʌ/ and /ɜ/ is 'vowel openness' in English; /ʌ/ is a bit more open than /ɜ/. In English, /ʌ/ is usually centralised. Another distinction is that /ʌ/ is usually shorter in length than /ɜ/.
- **/ɜ/ vs. /ɝ/:** /ɝ/ is called a 'rhotacised' vowel and is mostly found in [rhotic accents](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592) such as General American. As explained in [*A course in phonetics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Course_in_Phonetics.html?id=U4XaAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ladefoged and Johnson, /**ɝ**/ "does not fit on the chart because it can't be described simply in terms of high-low, front-back and rounded-unrounded"; it is an r-coloured or a rhotacised vowel. It involves another feature known as 'rhotacisation'. As Ladefoged and Johnson explain: "rhotacization describes an auditory property, the r-coloring, of a vowel". Rhotacisation occurs when certain vowels are followed by [ɹ]. R-coloured vowels can be articulated in two distinct ways, depending on the speaker [also from [*A course in phonetics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Course_in_Phonetics.html?id=U4XaAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ladefoged and Johnson (p94)]:

  - Some speakers have the tip of the tongue raised, as in a [retroflex consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroflex_consonant)
  - Others keep the tip down and produce a high bunched tongue position

Here's a clear illustration of both from [*A course in phonetics*](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Course_in_Phonetics.html?id=U4XaAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ladefoged and Johnson:

> > [image: tongue positions in r-coloured vowels]
>
> <sub>[the encircling is not a part of the original illustration, it's mine]</sub>

---

#### Notes

- Don't confuse /ɜ/ and /ɛ/; /ɜ/ is the vowel in 'bird', and  /ɛ/ in 'bed'
- The vowel /ʌ/ is the vowel in *CUT, TUT, STRUT, HUT, SHUT* etc.
- The rhotacised vowel /ɝ/ is only found in rhotic accents of English (chiefly American).
- The rhotacised vowel /ɝ/ is just a vowel, having been strongly influenced by a following R, just like nasalised vowels. [Non-rhotic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592) accents such as Southern Standard British English don't have rhotacised vowels.
- The difference between /ˈskɝːi/ and /ˈskɜr.i/ is that the vowel in the former has a rhotacised vowel i.e. it's a vowel, having been controlled by a following [ɹ] while the vowel in the latter is a central vowel followed by a consonant [ɹ].

Answer (score 1):

A minimal pairs exercise might be helpful in learning to both hear the difference and then to produce it in your own speech. Listen to pronunciation of both words in each pair and try to hear the difference:
fur/fair
blur/blare
purr/pair
burr/bear
her/hair
lure/lair
were/wear