# Transcribing Burj Al Arab

Tags: phrases, ipa

Could you transcribe "Burj Al Arab" with English phonetic symbols?  /bɜːdʒ  ˈæl ˈær.əb/?

> Hotel Burj Al Arab is where the idea of a seven-star hotel came to life

> Source:  [SkyScanner](https://www.skyscanner.com.au/news/the-worlds-most-opulent-7-star-hotels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Southern British English: [ˌbɜːd͡ʒ.əl.əˈræb]. In General American English: [ˌbɝd͡ʒ.əl.əˈɹæb]. I've also heard [ˌbɝd͡ʒ.əl.æˈɹæb] and [ˌbɝd͡ʒ.æl.æˈɹæb] (the *Al* is an Arabic word so I don't know how it's supposed to be pronounced, but I suspect it's with a schwa).

[ɝ] is called a [rhotacised vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/274338/106592) which is the rhotic equivalent of the non-rhotic vowel [ɜ]. Rhotacised vowels are mainly used in rhotic accents such as General American English.