# Is there any difference in pronunciation of 'wore' and 'were'?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

'Were' and 'wore' sound the same to me.

Is it true at native english users' ears?

from dictionary: [wɔ:r] for wore and  [wə́:r] for were

Comment: There’s a fairly universal answer to this particular question, but for similar questions you should specify the accent you’re interested in. For example, “marry”, “merry” and “Mary” are all pronounced the same in some US accents, but are all different in UK received pronunciation.

Comment: As a general rule, if the dictionary tells you two words have different pronunciations, then most native speakers can tell them apart. Although there may be some exceptions if you consider accents.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, they do not sound the same to native speakers. There's a striking difference between 'were' and 'wore'.

#### British English

**Were:** In British English, 'were' in its strong form (or slow speech) is pronounced with the [open-mid central unrounded vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/274338/106592) **/ɜː/**. In its weak form, it's pronounced with a [schwa](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272320/106592) **/ə/**.

**Wore:** It's pronounced with the [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272962/106592) **/ɔː/** (rhymes with *war, sore, law*).

Note that in Southern British English, they're pronounced without the /r/ sound because British English is [non-rhotic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592).

#### American English

**Were** is pronounced with an [r-coloured (rhotacised) vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/274338/106592)<sup>**1**</sup>: with /ɝ/ in its strong form and /ɚ/ in its weak form. (The rhotacised versions of central vowels are more common than others.)

**Wore** is pronounced with the [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272962/106592) /ɔ/ followed by the consonant /ɹ/

Another important difference is that of vowel roundedness; the vowel in *wore* is [rounded](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/274338/106592) while that of *were* isn't.

---

1. I've explained the vowel chart and the difference between /ɝ/ and /ɜ/ in the linked answer.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that in some dialects like that of Liverpool (UK) _were_ rhymes with _wear_ and _where_.

Comment: @mdewe Although not with Tyne and Wear. (I know, we could do this all day with English pronunciation! ;)

Comment: "Wore" and "war" don't just rhyme, they are homophones.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: In whose accent?  Not the one I hear around me (in the western US), or many others.  That's really the problem with this question.  Not to detract from this answer, but it really depends on who's talking.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm talking about the part where the answerer wrote "wore: ... rhymes with war", i.e. British English. Note that I said they "don't just rhyme", which implies someone else said they rhyme. I don't think it's possible for them to rhyme without also being homophones in any accent I can imagine.

Comment: Where is the front of the mouth? Behind your front lips? Behind your teeth?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. do you mean the front part of the tongue? i don't know where I've written front part of the mouth....  (i can't explain it as well as you can and because you and some other experienced users are not posting answers anymore, i try my best. i always enjoy reading your thorough answers and wish i could explain the way you did.... )

Comment: "the highest point of the tongue is positioned relatively **in front in the mouth**".

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Oh.. I mean the tongue is positioned in the front *relative to* the back vowels.

Comment: Ok, but you know that the "front" of the tongue is towards the back of the mouth right? What worries me about this post is that it would make learners think that English STRUT is a back vowel and that THOUGHT and NURSE were open mid, that NURSE was lower than schwa and so forth. But the symbols used for language-specific transcriptions **don't** represent the same values as those symbols when used in the IPA, most especially when it comes to vowels!

Comment: Well, when I say 'towards the back', I mean just under where your soft and hard palate meet. Kind of the high point of the arch of the roof of your mouth.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by homophone? "...two or more words having the same pronunciation...", so to, too, and two would be homophones in most dialects, but rhyming words in general wouldn't.  (I did look up the definition before writing that comment :-))

Comment: @jamesqf I was just talking about "wore" and "war". Other words may rhyme without being homophones.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for native English speakers "were" and "wore" are easy to tell apart.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "were" and "wore" are pronounced differently.

## List of Sentences Containing Words Which Rhyme With "Were"

- ***burrs*** come from thorny plants.
- A smaller percentage of wealthy Americans wear coats made from real animal **FUR** today than in the year 1927.

- My dog ***purrs*** like a cat.

- ***slurs*** are mean things to say to another person.
- I am ***sure*** that I want to cancel the my airplane trip.
- The ***whir*** of the fan lulled me to sleep.

## List of words Rhyming with "wore"

- In ***war***, it is permissible to kill a solider who never wronged you, but killing a man for raping your daughter is murder.
- pour
- chore
- boar
- bore
- core
- door
- drawer
- floor
- for
- four
- gore
- more
- oar
- or
- pour
- roar
- score
- shore
- snore
- soar
- sore
- your

Comment: Thx. Samuel. the last 'your' is not pronounced as 'sore'.

Comment: @Brandon: 'Your' and 'sore' do rhyme in most accents (I rhyme them in colloquial speech).

Comment: [ jʊr or jə(r) ] for AM, [ jɔː(r) ] for BM

Comment: @Brandon: Those are what's called 'citation forms', meaning they
 are the ideal pronunciations. In real life, no one pronounces words the way dictionaries do.

Comment: "sure" doesn't rhyme with "were" as far as I've heard - "sure" rhymes with either "wore", or in other accents it doesn't rhyme with either of them but instead with "endure", "mature" etc. All the other examples are good. :)

Comment: "War", "drawer", and "your" don't rhyme with "wore", at least in English as it's spoken around here.

Comment: @Brandon `your` and `sore` rhyme with each-other in American English.

Comment: @jamesqf "The man **wore** a shirt to dinner".... "The Germans went to **war** with France".... "The tale **wore** thin after 2 hours of listening" .... "`wore`" and "`war`" are pronounced identically in the United States. The words "`wore`" and "`war`" are heterographs of eachother.

Comment: @Samuel Muldoon: Not in my part (intermountain west) of the US, I assure you.  I don't do phonetic alphabet, but wore is pronounced with a distinct o sound, war with an a sound.  Of course regional accents may vary.

Comment: @jamesqf I have lived in Denver, Colorado most of my life. In Denver, most people pronounce "**wore**" (as in clothing) the same way as "**war**" (as in soldiers, bombs, etc...). Also, in every Hollywood movie I have ever seen, the words "**wore**" and "**war**" are pronounced the same way.